# Summation on an element inside nested dicts in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of nested dictionaries

```
timedata = [
        {'time': 1, 'distance': {'a': 300, 'b': 3}},
        {'time': 2, 'distance': {'a': 600, 'b': 1}},
        {'time': 3, 'distance': {'a': 600, 'b': 4}},
        {'time': 4, 'distance': {'a': 300, 'b': 3}},
  ]
```

Any ideas how to calculate the summation of 'a' from all dicts inside the list?

Comment: What have you tried, please show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go inside `timedata`, use `[]`, similarly for nestings inside it. To sum conttents, use `sum()`:

```
print(sum([di['distance']['a'] for di in timedata]))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
sum = 0
for i in timedata:
     sum += i['distance']['a']
print(sum)
```